# Best Asymmetric encryption algorithm available in java API?

Tags: java, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am following this article on [Encryption/Decryption](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170967&seqNum=4). Currently I am using RSA algorithm for encryption and decryption using private and public key respectively. 
 I am not sure whether RSA is good for asymmetric encryption or not.

Can you guys share your thought wheter RSA is best or not. If RSA is not best then please suggest me other algorithm name which can be used through java APIs.

Comment: If there was consensus on what "best" means, why would there be more than one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's good enough for your bank, it's (probably) good enough for your purposes. It's still secure (given a correct implementation and big enough keys). It's hard to pick the "best" algorithm, but RSA is certainly a well-trusted, secure algorithm.

Comment: what should be the key size. current keysize is 512. is it good enough?

Comment: No. Typical keysizes are usually 1,024 - 4,096. Refer to the [RSA Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm))